# How enable CORS policy in Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, cors, nest

Could you help me with this task?
I have front-end on Flutter (Android and iOs apps and the web platform)
On the back end, I use NestJS (there is an enable cors flag there)
I try to use images from foreign domains and it works on apps but unfortunately not on the web version.
I know that there are answers to `disabling security` and it works but only for local development.
Also, I tried run the web app with the
`--web-renderer html`
flag, and it worked too, but when I tried to use NetworkImage(URL) it caused an infinity loop.
p.s. If you need I can give some my code or flutter doctor.

I need that solution (if it is) to work in dev and in prod.